# Changing text font of title, figure and table captions in Thesis

Tags: fonts, captions, thesis

I am writing my thesis and downloaded from this [link](http://mdolab.net/hdr_resources.html).

I found that the text of the main title, figure and table captions have different text than the main text of the thesis. Anyone help to tell which part I need to change to fix that part?

In thesis`.tex`, there is a command:

`%\usepackage[margin=10pt,font={small,sf},format=hang,indention=-0.5cm,justification=centerlast]{caption}`

In this command if comment `font={small,sf},format=hang,`
then the font of the text and caption of the tables and figures are same. How can I change the font type in this to match with the font of the text? Also the title font is still same...

Comment: As it stands, I'm afraid your objectives are quite unclear. To improve the comprehensibility of your posting, it would really help if you provided a more precise link to the LaTeX template file(s). Aside: If your educational institution requires you to use the template file(s), it may not be a good idea to modify them.

Comment: If there is a template / example document available I would assume that the institute wants the thesis to look like the example document.

Comment: No it should not be like that. Its not official from the university. Thats why i want to change it